# Reading a template and creating a new XML file using the read template

Tags: c#, xml, templates, xmlreader, xmlwriter

I'm attempting to read a XML template, code below, and put this content to a new XML file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Format>
<Name title=""></Name>
<FormatA>
    <Scheme name="A" set="number" get="integer">
        <Sample set="number" get="integer">33</Sample>
    </Scheme>
</FormatA>
<FormatX>
    <Scheme name="A" set="number" get="integer">
        <Sample set="number" get="integer">44</Sample>
    </Scheme>
</FormatX>
</Format>
```

And will input values and write the title and a value for name. e.g When I enter "Counter" for the title and "Cnt" for the value. It will write

```
<Name title="Counter">Cnt</Name>
```

Basically, I'll just copy the contents of the template, put it in the new XML file with the inputted title and value.

Thank you for reading and who will answer my inquiry.

Comment: what is the question - have you tried any thing or you are clueless as where to start?

Comment: @VinayC, I have no idea to do this

Comment: @Anuraj, Counter is an sample input for the node Name's title

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried string.Format?

1. Create the Template XML file with
   Place Holders, like this {1}
2. Call
   String.Format(XmlContent,"Counter","Cnt")

Hope it helps.

Comment: @gibz357: XmlContent is string which contains all the XML Data.